# Fancyhdr for books

Tags: fancyhdr

I get confused with `fancyhdr`. Let's consider this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{A dummy document}
\author{John Doe}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Abstract}
\lipsum{2}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Neo}
\lipsum{8-12}
\section{Trinity}
\lipsum{13-20}
\chapter{Bar}
\section{Morpheus}
\lipsum{21-25}
\backmatter
\section{Appendix}
\lipsum{26}
\end{document}
```

I can note different header/footer styles:

1. Empty (title page)
2. No headers + header line + page number in roman (after title page)
3. No headers + page number in roman (page with tableofcontents)
4. Headers + page number in roman (other pages in frontmatter)
5. No headers + page number in arabic (chapter pages)
6. Headers + page numbers in arabic (other pages in mainmatter)

I don't really understand (2) and (3). How can I configure all these different configurations?

If I add the following it doesn't affect the titlepage, the chapter pages and the numbering type:

```
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CE]{Even}
\fancyhead[CO]{Odd}
```

How can I configure fancyhdr to:

- Remove headers/footers on empty pages?
- Configure header/footers on chapter pages?
- Configure header/footers on other pages?

Comment: Well, (2) is a "normal" page but since there hasn't been any `\chapter` yet the headers are empty. (3) is a normal `plain` page like (5). But I haven't used `fancyhdr` in eons so I can't really write an answer... But as far as the first question goes, there is the `emptypage` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Remove headers and footers on empty pages

The first question is not about `fancyhdr` is the behavior of `\cleardoblepage`. In order to remove headers and footers on empty pages I use the following code in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
  \def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \vspace*{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

### Configure headers and footers on chapter pages

`\chapter` resets the page style to plain by default. If you want to change the style of this page, try:

```
\chapter{Foo}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

### Headers and footers in other pages

An example on how to modify headers and footer on other pages:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %clear headers and footers
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} %page number on the left on even pages and the right of odd pages
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark} %chapter name in the center of odd pages
\fancyhead[CE]{\rightmark} %section title in the center of even pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %rule width
```

for this part you need to read a little more, because is difficult to make an example to illustrate every aspect of `fancyhdr`. Try something [basic](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers) or the [manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).